# Error during NetBox Installation, unable to create a superuser with manage.py

Tags: python, lua, centos

Python version: 3.6.8
NetBox version: 2.9.1
CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)

I am installing NetBox following the Documentation step by step:
https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/3-netbox/

I get stuck when I try to create or delete a superuser.
He creates the User but seems like he fails on the password. If I try to create a superuser it fails, trying to create a superuser afterward with the same name throws out "User already exists".

Error:

```
(venv) [root@ALTLX548 netbox]# cd /opt/netbox/netbox
(venv) [root@ALTLX548 netbox]# clear
(venv) [root@ALTLX548 netbox]# python3 manage.py createsuperuser
Username (leave blank to use 'root'): admin
Email address:
Password:
Password (again):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 79, in execute
    return super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 189, in handle
    self.UserModel._default_manager.db_manager(database).create_superuser(**user_data)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 157, in create_superuser
    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 140, in _create_user
    user.save(using=self._db)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 67, in save
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 751, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 800, in save_base
    update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using,
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 179, in send
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 179, in <listcomp>
    for receiver in self._live_receivers(sender)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cacheops/query.py", line 443, in _post_save
    invalidate_obj(instance, using=using)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cacheops/invalidation.py", line 36, in invalidate_obj
    invalidate_dict(model, get_obj_dict(model, obj), using=using)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/funcy/decorators.py", line 39, in wrapper
    return deco(call, *dargs, **dkwargs)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cacheops/transaction.py", line 63, in queue_when_in_transaction
    return call()
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/funcy/decorators.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/funcy/decorators.py", line 39, in wrapper
    return deco(call, *dargs, **dkwargs)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cacheops/redis.py", line 17, in handle_connection_failure
    return call()
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/funcy/decorators.py", line 60, in __call__
    return self._func(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cacheops/invalidation.py", line 26, in invalidate_dict
    json.dumps(obj_dict, default=str)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 4073, in __call__
    return client.evalsha(self.sha, len(keys), *args)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 3143, in evalsha
    return self.execute_command('EVALSHA', sha, numkeys, *keys_and_args)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 901, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 915, in parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "/opt/netbox/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 756, in read_response
    raise response
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: Error running script (call to f_0605214935a9ffcd4b9e5779300302540ff08da4): @user_script:36: @user_script: 36: Unknown Redis command called from Lua script
(venv) [root@ALTLX548 netbox]#
```

Comment: I am gonna load a snapshot and install everything from the fresh over the weekend. I will update this post if I find any possible solution.

Comment: A little late but I finally reinstalled netbox, this time I used ubuntu and not centos.
I could create the super user without any error.

Comment: Tried it again with Centos, same issue. Seems like an issue with netbox on centos that needs to be investigated from netbox team.

Comment: I was able to get it running under Centos, using Docker VM.
So the python vm runs in the docker vm and that works, not rly happy with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Quoting my comment here again, so i can mark this Thread as answered.

> I was able to get it running under Centos, using Docker VM. So the python vm runs in the docker vm and that works.

Answer (score 0):

Check the version of PostgreSQL yum gave you. NetBox requires 9.6 or later. I had to find RPMs of newer version via the PostgreSQL site, and yum localinstall

Check the Redis version on CentOS. The install guide notes version 4 or later is required. Yum repo gave me version 3.

Redis only offer source code :\

Found RPMs for later versions here https://pkgs.org/download/redis and did yum localinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case, Redis was deployed from Epel repository which is lower than the required version (at date 10/07/2020, Redis 4.0 or higher is required : [enter link description here](https://netbox.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation/2-redis/))